# SSO to angular 4 app

Tags: angular, single-sign-on

I'm trying to authenticate users from another app of mine to an Angular 4 based App, What i do to authenticate users currently is to save the user and the jwt in the localStorage,I found a suggestion to pass from the application B to the Web Api get the token and the user but i don't know where to put them so that Angular can recognize them since localstorage is domaine bound.

 thank you

Comment: localStorage is not secure, so it would be good to have a token service in the backend, the service providers just check against it.